Is there a rand function in Dafny?
I have been trying to model a set of concurrent chemical reactions in Dafny. Since these reactions occur with non-zero probabilities once they are enabled, I would like to model the probabilistic behavior. I might just need a simple uniform random function in Dafny, but could not seem to find much information. Any help would be appreciated.
I searched the Dafny online tutorial (https://dafny.org/dafny/OnlineTutorial/guide) and the language reference (https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef).

In the standard library there definitely is not. Dafny only added an official function for input/output last December. It's not really the best tool for probability. It's really more geared for verifying traditional cs algorithms.
However, some folks just put out a library for that though. https://github.com/dafny-lang/Dafny-VMC/tree/main
However, I suspect that you're really trying to calculate a probability for a certain event and there is a better tool for that. https://www.prismmodelchecker.org/
Example use case: https://buttondown.email/hillelwayne/archive/i-formally-modeled-dreidel-for-no-good-reason/

In order to choose some unspecified element from a set or a multiset, you can use :|.
method Choice <T> (A : multiset<T>) returns (a : T)
requires A != multiset {}
ensures a in A
{
    a :| a in A;
    return a;
}

For verification purposes that should be ok, but I don't know if that kind of choice has any of the desirable statistical properties. Moreover, Dafny sets are higher level than sets in most languages, and their intended use is verification and reasoning about properties. One should use other data structures for sets that will compile to executable code.
Hope that helps!
